# How can I change the position of this React component to fixed?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using the react-particles-webgl npm package to render this webgl canvas:

[image]

I want the canvas to take up the entire screen. When I change the position of this element to "fixed" in the Chrome Developer tools it takes up the entire screen. So I went and changed the inline style of the particle field element to <ParticleField style={{ position: "fixed" }} /> But it still says the position is relative in the chrome developer tools. How do I change this?

Comment: i suppose you are using a wrapper library. those are always wrapping the real canvas with a div which have width and height of its own. our team used react-konva and i need to specifically set the width and height to do the responsiveness. what we did is wrap the JSX inside a div ..give that div a ref...get innerHeight and width and then pass down those sizes as props to the library JSX and then set it. maybe you try that way?

Answer (score 1):

This means ParticleField may not have style prop. You can either add style as prop for ParticleField, or wrap ParticleField with a div then use style={{position:fixed}} for that div

```
<div style={{ position: "fixed" }}><ParticleField  /></div>
```

Comment: Yes I tried wrapping ParticleField with a div however that doesn't work either. How would add style as a prop?

Answer (score 0):

[Look at the source](https://github.com/tim-soft/react-particles-webgl/blob/master/src/ParticleField.js) of the library you're using. The key part would be the return statement in the component, which is effectively your render:

```js
return (
    <scene>
      <group ref={group}>
        {/* Bounding box that particles exist inside of */}
        {showCube && (
          <boxHelper>
            <mesh name="object">
              <meshBasicMaterial
                attach="material"
                color="white"
                blending={AdditiveBlending}
                wireframe
                transparent
              />
              <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[r, r, r]} />
            </mesh>
          </boxHelper>
        )}
        {/* Lines connecting particles */}
        {lines.visible && (
          <lineSegments
            geometry={lineMeshGeometry}
            material={lineMeshMaterial}
          />
        )}

        {/* Particles */}
        {particles.visible && (
          <points geometry={pointCloudGeometry} material={pointMaterial} />
        )}
      </group>
    </scene>
  );
```

I would target `<scene style={{ position:fixed; }}>` based on what I see here. Another option might be to feed it through something like `styled-components` as an HOC.